# How to transpose Excel Pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have source table where I have every number category in separate column (something like already pivoted).

I would like to create pivot table, where division are in columns and number category in rows.

I need to transpose columns with rows from this layout:

[image: current layout]
[image: current pivot fields]

to something like this:

[image: desired layout]

Is it possible within standard pivot without Power query and unpivoting my data? (I guess with PQ it would be bigger and took longer to refresh).

Comment: In the pivot field pane, drag Values from the Columns box to the Rows box, and drag Divisions from the Rows box to the Columns box.

Comment: Jenn, thanks so much. It really works. Please put it as a answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the pivot field pane, drag Values from the Columns box to the Rows box, and drag Divisions from the Rows box to the Columns box.